# Why do Ubuntu system packages show up with pip freeze/how do I clean up pip freeze?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I accidentally installed jupyter and all its dependent packages outside of venv. I'm trying to delete them all by hand, but there are a lot of other packages too (`command-not-found`,`systemd-python`, `ubuntu-drivers-common`, `python-debian`) that I'm not sure I can delete. Yet they show up at pip freeze. How I can clean it up? I wanna work with packages in venvs only.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
pip freeze --local
```

will return only packages installed inside venv.

Don't try to remove the packages you listed, removing them might break you OS installation.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. Still I have 2 questions: how do I know which ones I can remove? Cause thereis more than just those. And 2: why do they show up now? They didn't before

Comment: I don't know, to be honest.